# Link to a question directly targeting one of the answers

Tags: support, editing, hyperlinks

How is it feasible to make a link that targets *directly* a specific answer of a stack exchange question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below each answer is a "share" link.  If you click on it you can copy a URL that is a link to that particular answer.  BTW, this is a good way to cite another user's answer in your own responses.

v               pretty much right below this !